# Pycharm Pro + Cloudformation plugin = not working properly

Tags: pycharm, aws-cloudformation

I'm using PyCharm Pro 2019.2.
I want to use the Cloudformation Plugin to make use of its autocompletion.

For some reason, the autocomplete only works in some spots, but not in others.
Here a few examples, where one specific indent works, but not the others.

[image: no_sugg_1]

[image: sugg_1]

[image: no_sugg_2]

What I tried:
 - use JSON instead of yaml, same thing
 - remove plugin and add it again

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: If you're willing to switch editors for CloudFormation autocompletion: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kddejong.vscode-cfn-lint